Race Condition In Two Threads
I've been banging my head against my table to find the concurrency bug in the following code. My Friend I have been arguing about it for quite some time and we cannot determine a scenario in which both t1 and t2 access buffer concurrently. We're assuming a relatively simple scheduler with only one core on a 386 CPU.
I am convinced that the buffer_read_complete.load test-and-set is wrong here and requires a buffer_read_complete.compare_exchange_weak. I just cannot reason through the edge-case which leads to concurrent access of buffer.
#include <atomic>

void wcpy(char*);
void rcpy(char*);

static char buffer[256];
static std::atomic<bool> buffer_write_complete = false;
static std::atomic<bool> buffer_read_complete = true;

void t1() {
    while (true) {
        if (buffer_read_complete.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)) {
            buffer_read_complete.store(false, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
            wcpy(buffer);
            buffer_write_complete.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
        }
    }
}

void t2() {
    while (true) {
        if (buffer_write_complete.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)) {
            buffer_write_complete.store(false, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
            rcpy(buffer);
            buffer_read_complete.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
        }
    }
}


with std::memory_order_seq_cst a store is equivalent to a release, while a compare_exchange is equivalent to an acq_rel, wcpy can be reordered before a release, but not before an acq_rel.

I don't see any race conditions here, for what it's worth. Looks valid to me (though pointless; you could just as well have a single thread calling wcpy then rcpy in a loop).

@AhmedAEK yes, but even if it is, then where's the race? The real question is if read complete and write complete can be true at the same time, which does not seem possible to me.
